# Determine which javascript function is being triggered on element change

Tags: javascript, vb.net, browser

I have a page that has two drop down lists. When the first dropdown list's value is changed, some function is triggered that updates the values of the second list depending on what is selected in the first list.

Is there some tool similar to FireBug, for example, that would tell me what function is being triggered by the updating of the drop down list? There is no "onChange" parameter in the Select element.

If I change the selected item manually by clicking on the element, this function is being triggered. But if I change the selected item programmatically using something such as:

```
MyElement.SetAttribute("SelectedIndex", 10)
```

the function to update the other field is not being fired. How can I find which function should be fired and how will I trigger it?

I am using VB.Net and loading/manipulating the page in a web browser control.

Not sure if it makes a difference, but the dropdown elemet has some attributes that I am not familiar with, such as "ng-model" and "ng-change".

Comment: `ng-` attributes comes from the AngularJS library.